# How to select an element that its value is greater than zero

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I am trying to find an element that its data-stock value is greater than 0. I can find elements with specific stock values using:
  `findElement(By.xpath("//div[@data-stock='2']"))`
  But since the stock is always changing I want to find the first element that has data-stock greater than zero using xpath or css. Tried using `"//div[@data-stock!='0']"` but it doesn't work.

```
<div class="product" data-price="100.00" data-stock="0">...<div>
<div class="product" data-price="30.00" data-stock="2">...<div>
<div class="product" data-price="3.00" data-stock="10">...<div>
```

I want to use `findElement()` and get the first element with stock greater than zero, which in this case is the second one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try `findElement(By.xpath("//div[@data-stock > 0]));` and let me know if that is useful.

btw: I find https://www.freeformatter.com/xpath-tester.html useful when playing with xpath.

:)

Comment: It worked perfectly! Thanks for your help and for sharing this website.

Comment: @AnyVictor Great! My pleasure! :) Please feel free to mark the question as answered. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers. Thanks!